# Macro "Doesn't Work" From Call on Separate Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This macro works as intended, from a button on the Batch Input sheet:

```
Sub BatchTriggerOFF()

    Sheets("Batch Input").Unprotect
    Sheets("Batch Input").Range("G3:J3").Value = "Off"
    Sheets("SQL LOGIC").Calculate
    Sheets("Batch Input").Range("A12").Select
    Sheets("Batch Input").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 12")).ZOrder msoSendToBack
    Sheets("Batch Input").Protect

End Sub
```

However, when BatchTriggerOFF is called from a different sheet in the same workbook, the macro neither changes the Range("G3:J3").Value nor Shapes.Range(Array("Group 12")).ZOrder msoSendToBack. There is no error message.

```
If Sheets("SQL LOGIC").Range("B1") = "On" Then Call BatchTriggerOFF
```

I've tried unprotecting the Batch Input sheet beforehand, messing with Sheets("Batch Input").Activate, Sheets("Batch Input").Select, and even tried pasting the BatchTriggerOFF line by line VBA directly into the second macro, to no avail.

What is causing BatchTriggerOFF to seemingly not run when called from the second macro/sheet?

Comment: What happens if you step through with `F8`?

Comment: Are you working in a `Sheet Module` or `Standard module`?  That is important to this question.  Additionally, avoid `Call` as it is deprecated; try using `Application.Run "macroName", arg1, arg2` (uses late binding).

Comment: Also, I get "compile error: sub or function not defined" when I try to `Call SomeInaccessibleProcedure` - I challenge the "there is no error message" premise: if the procedure isn't in scope, then the code can't compile. If the procedure is in scope, then the procedure is invoked. We're going to need more details. Please answer @Cyril's questions.

Comment: @Cyril, if I understand correctly, I believe I am in a Standard module, as all the macros are under the Modules folder. Is that correct? Also, your comment regarding Call, are you saying it won't work with all versions of Excel or something else?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, when I say there is no error message, the second line which calls the BatchTriggerOFF doesn't throw any errors... And now I know why - because it's not actually calling BatchTriggerOFF. I suppose this means something is inherently wrong with the second code I've provided, likely not actively running when the value in Range("B1") is changed?

Comment: Code doesn't just run magically on its own, it needs something to call it - public procedures in a (not private) standard module can be invoked from the *Macros* list in the developer tab, but if you want code invoked when a certain specific sheet/cell is changed, you need to handle that sheet's `Change` event, and inspect its `Target` parameter to see if the changed cell is something you want to act upon, i.e. whether it's cell B1 of that sheet.

Comment: As for `Call`, it will work in any version of VBA (Excel is irrelevant here) - what Cyril meant was that you can simply omit it. `Call DoSomething(42)` is 100% equivalent to `DoSomething 42`.

Comment: Debug > Compile VBAProject; getting the compile error now? Also make sure every module says `Option Explicit` at the top. You can (should) make this systematic, in Tools > Options, look for a "require variable declaration" checkbox, make sure it's checked.

Comment: I've edited and undeleted my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *[...] something is inherently wrong with the second code I've provided, likely not actively running when the value in Range("B1") is changed?*

Exactly. A procedure that's in a standard module needs *something, somewhere* to invoke it. Could be a shape or button on the worksheet, could be other VBA code, but *something* needs to invoke it *somehow*.

No procedure is going to just know to run when `Range("B1")` is changed on `Sheets("SQL LOGIC")`: you need to have code that's "triggered" when a cell is changed on that sheet.

The way to do this, is to handle the worksheet module's `Change` event. Find your "SQL LOGIC" sheet in the VBE's *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), double-click it. In the code-behind module for that specific worksheet, select `Worksheet` from the left-side dropdown at the top of the code pane; the right-side dropdown should say `SelectionChange`, and the VBE should have added a private procedure that looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Select `Change` from the right-side dropdown; the VBE creates a private procedure that looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Now delete the `SelectionChange` handler, you don't need it unless you need to track cells that the user has *selected*. Since we want to track cells that have *changed*, we'll use the `Change` worksheet event. This procedure will be invoked whenever the user **or your code** changes anything on that sheet.

Since we only care to run code when a *specific cell* is changed, we need a condition here, involving the `Target` parameter. Using the `Application.Intersect` function, we can get a `Range` object reference that's `Nothing` if the two specified ranges don't intersect; we can use this information to bail out if it's not B1 that changed:

```
If Application.Intersect(Me.Range("B1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Any code written after that condition inside the `Worksheet.Change` event handler procedure, will only run after the value of cell B1 was modified - either by the user typing in a value, or by any other code writing to that cell (you need to toggle `Application.EnableEvents` off if you have to prevent firing that event when it's code doing the changes and you don't want the handler to run).

Now, it looks like cell B1 isn't going to *change*, rather, it looks like it contains a formula whose result might change after making changes to the "Batch Input" sheet.

If that's the case, then the `Change` event will not be fired when `B1` recalculates and now evaluates to a new value, because the cell didn't *change*, only its result.

If that's your scenario, then you want to handle the `Calculate` worksheet event, and have *that* be your trigger:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Range("B1").Value = "On" Then BatchTriggerOFF
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Following your direction, I was able to make it work as desired. I plan to take a class or something in the near future and am good at piecing together what I need by referencing VBA from other projects, but I am still very much a beginner. I cannot thank you enough for clearly explaining what I did incorrectly and how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your sub to be called from any (sheet) module, move it in a module! The function/sub in the sheet module cannot be called without specifying the module name where it belongs, like you will be able to do in a module.

Comment: FWIW "The function/sub in the sheet module are private, even if you do not define them in this way" is disinformation.

Comment: @ Mathieu Guindon : You are right... I've just wanted to say that the function cannot be called like a public one, but the way I did it is wrong. I will correct the answer.